# Custom events in .Net Microframework

Tags: c#, events, .net-micro-framework, netduino

I want to create a simple `PushButton` class which wraps an `InterruptPort`. I'd like to give it two simple `Up` and `Down` events which are triggered when the port is high and low.

Normally I'd do it like this:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Up;
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> Down;
```

But there's no `EventHandler` class? How should I do it then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET Micro Framework does not support generics, but the non-generic [`EventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh400199.aspx) is still available.

So you can use it like:

```
public event EventHandler Up;
public event EventHandler Down;
```

> **Namespace**: Microsoft.SPOT
>
> **Assembly**: Microsoft.SPOT.TinyCore (in microsoft.spot.tinycore.dll)

Comment: What namespace/assembly is that defined in? VS C# 2010 Express just wants me to generate class `EventHandler` when I try that.

Comment: Aah, there we go. That one wasn't added by default. Thanks!